# Make the full width of input field inside an xeditable using angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

How could I enable the 100% width of each cell when it is in edit status with xeditable plugin?

I tried to put these style

```
<style>
  div[ng-controller] { margin: 10px; }
  .table {width: 100% }
  form[editable-form] > div {margin: 10px 0;}
  .editable-wrap {
      width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

And this option in angular app, but it couldn't work as well.

```
app.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
});
```

[image: inline]

[image: inline]

Here's the DEMO page http://106.185.55.97:3001/ngAdmin/admin.html#/admin/banks/index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple CSS to apply 100% width to input

```
.editable-controls input {
    width: 100%
}
```

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
.editable-wrap .editable-input {
   display: block;
   width: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.editable-wrap input{
      width: 100%;
  }
```